# IIS MVC Authentication - Trusted Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, trusted

There are two domains (A and B). The two domains are in trusted relationship.
There is an IIS web server in the A domain.

In Visual Studio, I created an MVC project and it is configured in Controller for Windows authentication.
I read the data like this:

- u = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower ();

The user in A domain is called Alex. The user in the B is Ben.

If Alex opens the page from his machine (computer is in the A domain), then everything works nicely.

- Automatically comes A\Alex

If Ben opens the page from his computer (computer is in B domain), then:

- By default, it comes the authentication windows! But if I give this data, everything works fine.

  - A\Alex + password: OK
  - B\Ben + password: OK
- I even tried:

  - Alex + password: OK
  - Ben + password: It was not good (but the webserver is in the A domain, so that is no problem)
- And if I add the page in IE/Security to "Local Intranet" then:

  - Automatically comes to B\Ben

So far, everything is fine and works accordingly. I can't find the solution for the next (and have tried a lot of things...)

If we use an independent machine from a third domain or even a mobile phone, then:

- Request Authentication:

  - A\Alex + password: OK
  - Alex + password: OK (Up this point is everything as I expected!)
  - B\Ben + password: NOT OK (WHY?!?!?)

Any idea what might be the problem?
Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT:
In the controller is:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
 {
```

web.config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is configured in Controller for Windows authentication"? BTW, it is bad idea to call `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User`. Always use `Controller.User`.

Comment: Controller is: [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
...

And web.config is:
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

Comment: Please edit your question to include new info, and well format them so others can review it. Don't use comments for that.